# R: issue with scaling of map in R (readOGR, ggplot)

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I import a shape file of the European Region incl. Russia in R using

```
ERMap <- readOGR(dsn = sfPath, layer = "general_2011_onlyEURO")
positions <- fortify(ERMap, region = "ISO_3_CODE")
```

I use  `plot(ERMap)` to plot the raw map. Issue 1: The most eastern part of Russia is cut off and presented on the most western part of the map.

I assign some data to the countries of the map regions and finally get the final map using

```
p <- ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = plotData, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,
    fill =  plotData$value), color = "black", size = 0.25)
```

Issue 2: in addition to the cutting off, the map is compressed horizontally.

The imported shape file (ERMap):

```
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
         min       max
x -179.99891 179.99841
y   29.48892  81.49686
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Data attributes:
      CNTRY_TERR      SOVEREIGN    ISO_3_CODE   ISO_2_CODE    UN_CODE         WHO_CODE    WHO_REGION
 Albania   : 1   Albania   : 1   ALB    : 1   AD     : 1   Min.   :  0.0   Min.   :   0   EURO:53   
 Andorra   : 1   Andorra   : 1   AND    : 1   AL     : 1   1st Qu.:203.0   1st Qu.:4030             
 Armenia   : 1   Armenia   : 1   ARM    : 1   AM     : 1   Median :398.0   Median :4180             
 Austria   : 1   Austria   : 1   AUT    : 1   AT     : 1   Mean   :412.4   Mean   :3954             
 Azerbaijan: 1   Azerbaijan: 1   AZE    : 1   AZ     : 1   3rd Qu.:643.0   3rd Qu.:4260             
 Belarus   : 1   Belarus   : 1   BEL    : 1   BA     : 1   Max.   :860.0   Max.   :4335             
 (Other)   :47   (Other)   :47   (Other):47   (Other):47                                            
        WHO_STATUS   REAL_VALUE    
 Member state:53   Min.   :0.0000  
                   1st Qu.:0.0000  
                   Median :0.0000  
                   Mean   :0.4717  
                   3rd Qu.:0.0000  
                   Max.   :7.0000
```

My plotted data looks like that

```
   id     long      lat group   value
1 ALB 19.69318 42.67708 ALB.1 5.67525
2 ALB 20.54673 42.25031 ALB.1 5.67525
3 ALB 20.50406 41.22604 ALB.1 5.67525
4 ALB 21.10155 40.73524 ALB.1 5.67525
5 ALB 20.80280 40.09507 ALB.1 5.67525
6 ALB 20.11996 39.54026 ALB.1 5.67525
```

Summary of plot data presents

```
> summary(plotData)
       id            long              lat            group          value       
 SMR    : 368   Min.   :-180.00   Min.   :29.49   AND.1  : 361   Min.   : 4.182  
 AND    : 367   1st Qu.:   6.40   1st Qu.:41.04   MCO.1  : 361   1st Qu.: 7.339  
 MCO    : 361   Median :  14.23   Median :43.51   SMR.1  : 361   Median : 9.081  
 RUS    : 323   Mean   :  24.07   Mean   :47.06   RUS.1  : 231   Mean   : 9.551  
 KAZ    :  54   3rd Qu.:  28.80   3rd Qu.:49.95   KAZ.1  :  54   3rd Qu.:13.470  
 FRA    :  52   Max.   : 180.00   Max.   :81.50   NOR.1  :  49   Max.   :14.602  
 (Other):1070                                     (Other):1178   NA's   :1029
```

I am quite new using maps/ggplot in R and would very much appreciate some hints where to start solving these issues.

My questions are:

- How can I avoid a cut off of parts of the map?
- How can I scale the map to avoid vertical compression?

Comment: Without data, chance to get any answer is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but it might be a good idea to fortify your data before plotting it.

```
ERmap.f<-fortify(ERmap)
```

Than for the vertical compression it helps to use the `coord_map()` function within ggplot this would look like this:

```
p <- ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = ERmap.f, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,
    fill =  plotData$value), color = "black", size = 0.25)+
    coord_map()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! coord_map() solved issue 2 with the compression. Unfortunately there is still the cutting of the map (issue 1).

Comment: I found an easy solution to avoid the cutting of Russia for long > 180°. I just added 360° for for long values of Russia which are < 0°.  I still have a vertical line where the cutting was but the map is not separated any more.

Comment: Ok, I see where the problem is located and I think it has to do with your shape file. There might be a nicer solution than your own one with the help of some of the geo packages such as `raster` or `rgdal` but I am not that expirienced with them. If you made your shape file yourself this question on the gis stackexchange might help you http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72621/how-to-render-area-that-crosses-180%C2%B0